# Chinese Restaurant Process

Tags: dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

I want to implement *Chinese Restaurant Process* representation of *Dirichlet Process* for random partitions. The problem setup is as follows:

I have some data (customers) which I have to randomly group (assign table). According to CRP,

- First customer **C1** will always choose first *empty table* i.e.
  **T1**
- Second customer **C2** will choose **T1** with *probability*

$P(T1) = c / (n - 1 + α)$

and **C2** will choose **T2** with *probability*

$P(T2) = α / (n - 1 + α)$

where $c$ is number of customer sitting at *existing table* and $n$ is *total number of customers*.

My 3 questions are:

**1.  Choosing New Table**

- *How to decide that **C2** will choose which table? Should **C2** choose table with greater probability from $P(T1)$ and $P(T2)$?*

**2.  Same Probability value for Existing & New Table**

For instance, **C2** have chosen **T2**, whereas at this stage $P(T1)$ and  $P(T2)$ are same as:

$P(T1) = 1/(2 + α)$ and
$P(T2) = 1/(2 + α)$ Now

- *How to decide **C3** will choose which table?*

**3.  Choosing from more than 1 Existing Tables**

For another instance, if there have been assigned $3$ tables yet and $4th$ table will be new table, as we have a *single **new** table probability value* and *several existing tables probability values*, then

- *How to decide that next customer choose which table from existing $3$ tables?*

Comment: @Anony-Mousse _Questions_ are related to group assignment concept of _Chinese Restaurant Process_

Comment: If it is harder to get answer of this question at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), then where else?

Comment: Also you need to have more patience. It may take a week or even a month to get a good answer from *volunteers*.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse May be I'm not getting your point but what I think, we should know the answers to these questions (at least Question No. 1 and Question No. 3) before we calculate _probabilities_. Can you please answer those questions, if its crystal clear to you what I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be very precise about what $c$ and $n$ are.

Let $c_i$ be the number of customers at table $i$.

Let $n$ be the customer number, i.e. $n-1$ clients are *already* seated at all tables.

Let $k$ be the current number of tables.

Then randomly choose a table using this probabilities:
$$
P(T_i) =
\begin{cases}
c_i / (n - 1 + \alpha) & \text{ for }i\leq k
\\
\alpha / (n - 1 + \alpha) & \text{ for } i = k +1
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This is a total distribution, because
$$
\sum_i P(T_i)
=
\frac{\sum c_i + \alpha}{n - 1 + \alpha}
=
\frac{n -1 + \alpha}{n - 1 + \alpha}
= 1
$$
Therefore, you can draw a random number such that exactly one of these cases happens; i.e. the customer chooses exactly one table.

If $n=1$, $k=0$, then the probability of choosing the first (new) table is $\alpha/\alpha=1$.

Just reading this in a book only gets you halfway. What **you need to learn is to work out such details yourself**. The *way* to figure out these things is where you learn, not by looking at the final result.

This is **not a clustering algorithm**. It is a random stochastic process to simulate certain data distributions. But it is not based on any data. It is a theoretical model to back certain considerations. Judging from your earlier questions, it appears as if you were mislead to believe this could be easily used to cluster some text data?

Comment: @Anony--Thanks a lot! But following many CRP explanations, it has been used as clustering as considering _tables_ as _clusters_ and _customers_ as _cluster members_. i.e. _group assignment_ to customers

Comment: Using a theoretical model does not mean it has been simulated *literally*, because then it would assign *randomly*. And you probably don't want *random* clusters. What people do is use such as process to optimize parameters for the actual clustering, e.g. the number of clusters. You would use the CRP to estimate the number of tables, and the data to estimate alpha in return; then iterate this again and again to optimize these parameters for your actual clustering. It is a so called **prior**. But again, you need much more than CRP, unless you want random clusters.

Comment: @Anony--As we will have two _probability values_ for `i<=k` and for `i=k+1`, so how will we decide that _instance_ will go to which side? Will it be decided on behalf of **greater** _probability value?_

Comment: You have k+1 probability values, not 2. They sum to 1, and that allows you to draw the table as a random variable from this distribution.

Comment: @Anony--Right you mean that, for instance if we have 6 probability values (i.e. 6 existing tables also referred as _k_) then we choose **randomly** from these 6 probabilities to draw a table for new customer. Am I right?

Comment: @Anony--If I'm right as we would choose **randomly** from _probabilities_, then in each iteration and keeping _number of customers_ and _alpha_ value **_same_**, we'll get different _number of tables_ in result. Then **how will it converge OR When will we stop iterating?**

Comment: It's not a convergent process. It will add one new customer each time you call it, and it will also add a new table with probability T(k+1). Again, this is an infinite random process, not a clustering algorithm that would converge to a "good" clustering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process

Comment: @Anony--As we can use _Collapsed Gibbs Sampling_ to estimate cluster assignments, can't we use CRP to estimate same ?

Comment: Of course it can be used in an optimization process, as mentioned before. It can be used as a prior to determine the number of clusters *if* you in turn estimate alpha, too. This gives the optimization process the ability to vary the number of clusters. But standalone (not integrated in a whole graphical model) it cannot cluster data.

Comment: +1 answer. I was under the same impression as the OP. Your comments -- especially your first reply -- were a real breakthrough for me to actually understand how this all works.